# math rules when having 2 variables in Big-O

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I came across the following in some lecture notes:

```
O(log n) + O(log m) = O(log n + log m ) = O(log (m + n))
```

that last step to `O(log(m+n))` seems weird to me because `O(log(m+n))` grows slower than `O(log n + log m )`.

The logarithm rules certainly tell that `log(n) + log(m)` is `log(n.m)`, though is the above given in the lecture notes, valid under Big-O ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $\color{red}{O(\log(m+n))=O(\log(n) + \log(m))}$, since, for every $m\geqslant2$ and $n\geqslant2$, $$m+n\leqslant m\cdot n\leqslant(m+n)^2,
$$
hence
$$
\log(m+n)\leqslant\log(m)+\log(n)\leqslant2\cdot\log(m+n).$$

Answer (score 1):

It's crucial to note that big-O notation describes the limiting behaviour as $n,m\to\infty$. In this limit, $\log(n)+\log(m)$ and $\log(n+m)$ behave identically so it's perfectly consistent.